# How do I render three.js in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, three.js

How do I render three.js code in node.js?

I'd like to export from blender, then open the export through `fs` and render a scene with it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is kind of a smelly implementation, but the key parts to remember are the part where the geometry is created, everything else is pretty straightforward.  I'm mostly putting this here for my own reference later, but it does work and it's cool to have 3d rendering in nodejs.  oh yea it requires canvas to work too.

it relies on `three.js` npm module
https://github.com/uniba/node-three.js

```
fs = require("fs")

THREE = require("three.js")
join = require("path").join

app.get '/test/top_:top_id/side_:side_id/x_:x/y_:y.jpg', (req, res, next) =>

  width = 660
  height = 500

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, width / height, 1, 1000)
  scene = new THREE.Scene()
  renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer( )
  renderer.setSize width, height

  camera.position.z = 100

  camera_container = new THREE.Object3D
  scene.add camera_container
  camera_container.add camera

  camera.position.z = 75

  # We have one background plane
  plane_image = new Image
  plane_image.src = fs.readFileSync TOP_DIR + "public/images/vtx_logo.jpg"
  texture = new THREE.Texture plane_image, new THREE.UVMapping()
  texture.needsUpdate = true

  loader = new THREE.JSONLoader()

  geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(200, 200)
  material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial
    color       : 0x698144
    #shading        : THREE.SmoothShading
    map     : texture
    overdraw: true
  plane = new THREE.Mesh geometry, material
  plane.position.z = -50
  plane.position.y = -4
  plane.position.x = 4.5

  # We also have an object in the foreground
  scene.add plane
  geometry = false
  loader.createModel JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(TOP_DIR + 'public/blender_export.json')), (done) =>
    geometry = done

  # Imager.texture gives us a canvas based on some code that grabs specific info
  texture = new THREE.Texture (Imager.texture req.params.side_id, req.params.top_id), new THREE.UVMapping()
  texture.needsUpdate = true

  material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial
    color: 0xaaaaaa
    map: texture
    overdraw: true
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh geometry, material

  mesh.rotation.x = parseFloat req.params.x
  mesh.rotation.y = parseFloat req.params.y

  scene.add mesh
  mesh.dynamic = true
  renderer.render scene, camera

  renderer.domElement.toBuffer (err, buf) ->
    res.contentType 'image/jpg'
    res.send buf
```

If you get an error `cannot find ./lib/Three`:

The `three.js` module I mentioned might point to an old version of three internally.  I remember having to go into the module and edit a file that `require('./lib/Three')` to `require('./lib/three')`.  I guess he included a non specific three in his package.json, so it got updated without his npm module being updated.. could be fixed by now

Comment: TIL: Three.js could run on node.js.

Comment: Indeed as of r61 Three.js no longer has any references to `window` and is therefore usable in node.js. Nice code @Funkodebat rendering the buffer to an image and passing it back. How's the performance online?

Comment: The library referenced uses jsdom to hack a fake window and open three inside of that, changing what it needs to along the way.  It's super hard to find for some reason, I left a link

Comment: @Darryl_Lehmann I don't notice any slowness.  This is the fallback to the fallback.  It should run webgl in clients browsers.  If that fails, it goes to the app server and the app server is connected through socket.io to an onsite GPU ubuntu box with a browser window open that will render webgl and pass it back to server, back to customer.  If our GPU ubuntu box is down, then this code runs and renders the image, since it can only do canvas and doesn't look as pretty, but its still cool to have :)

Comment: Another note, I remember having to edit a require('lib/Three') to require('lib/three') within the mentioned module.  I think his package.json is probably very non-specific.  You should get an error saying the library can't find Three, but if you look, three is present.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any reason why you couldn't use something like [electron](https://electron.atom.io/), which allows you to create desktop apps and implement node.js in them. This isn't an exact answer to the question, but for the sake of people looking for something like this, I will post this answer

Comment: Node-webkit is like an unlocked browser.. it still runs on a computer, not so much a server.  I've done methods where a virtual machine runs (with a video card), and renders threejs in the virtual machine's browser, then sends a screenshot to the server, and then to the person asking for it.  I'd use a browser or nw for this today.  I suppose you could incorporate the server to the NW instance that renders, but you still need a headed server either way.  Also, NW didn't exist 4 years ago when this question was asked.

Answer (score -17):

You should not run code for visuals on the server really, if you are doing computationally expensive stuff on the server you will need to be prepared to put a considerable buk into those. What you need is to delegate exporting and rendering to the client machines.

Comment: First, that is not what OP asked for. Second - node.js is not only for servers.

Comment: ^ I'm a stanch defender of node.js, and am often saying that serving webpages is the least interesting feature of node.

Comment: Yes, let's downvote anybody who considers offering advice on optimization

Comment: It depends on what the requirements are.  If, say, I want to batch render or compose images for sharing on social media, or print-ready artwork, then there is no Javascript-capable client available, and so headless rendering is very desirable.

"Should not" advice that assumes a particular scenario can be incredibly obnoxious. Instead, perhaps better to give the OP the benefit of the doubt and _suggest_ they could try it differently if the circumstances fit.