# How to render three.js server-side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js

How can I render three.js server side? At the moment our website renders player avatars using three.js locally, however that issues security things as well as potential bugs with people with less-end computers (people can inject the code into console and have it render god knows what..)

I looked into using node.js but all documentation on that is vague and appears to be quite outdated..

Any help would be useful

Current local: http://pastebin.com/yv5Qamfz

Comment: People will always be able to open their console and have the ability to "render god knows what". `three.js` is a client side library. Even if you dynamically generate markup server-side, the code will still be executed client-side. Also, [node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/)  is generally always up to date.

Comment: So I don't suppose there is another code or way to render server-side? :/

Comment: You could write something that renders the model serverside and somehow streams it to the front-end, but I reckon you are better off just using three.js clientside as intended

Answer (score 5):

There are several discussions about using three.js on node.js on the three.js GitHub page. Check for example:

- [Use Three.js functions in node.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2182)
- [node.js server rendering with node-webgl and/or headless-gl](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/7085)

There is also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162510/how-do-i-render-three-js-in-node-js) on stackoverflow which could be considered a duplicate of your question.

This one is dealing with a project called **[node-three.js](https://github.com/nulltask/node-three.js)** on GitHub. It will support rendering in three.js on node.js. Not sure if it does exactly what you want (I have no first hand experience with this library) but worth checking it out I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [blog post](https://cliffordhall.com/2016/09/render-three-js-videos-on-client-or-server/). Its from a few years ago, but trying to solve a similar issue. Apparently there isn't an off-the-shelf solution yet.

Perhaps you could render it client-side as you are currently doing, but inside a hidden div, and then render the canvas to an image and display the image to the user? [See here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52116877/save-hidden-div-as-canvas-image).

Comment: Even if its in a hidden div, any client could make a browser extension that injects code into that div