# How to draw a 3D model in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, three.js, 3d

I've got a browser client talking to an ASP.NET Core C# backend. On the browser I am using three.js to draw 3D building models. The data I use for the model is saved to the server as a job. The browser can recall that job and redisplay the 3D model. That part is working just fine. The models are not terribly complicated. They are basic buildings not complicated photo realistic models of people :-)

At various points in time I need to be able to generate a report on the server that includes pictures of the 3D model. I cannot rely on the client to generate the pictures for me. So I am after a library, at a similar abstraction level  to threejs, that I can use in an ASP.NET Core C# web server to draw the 3D model, and save it to a PNG for inclusion in the report.

Suggestions for such a library?

Answer (score 0):

You can use three.js to render serverside, by adding node.js to the mix.

[How to render three.js server-side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051411/how-to-render-three-js-server-side)

Comment: I guess that's a solution. Not that I have any nodejs experience and not sure I want to add it into the mix. Will keep it in mind.

Comment: Yeah. That's the most straightforward solution. WebGL is a browser technology, so unless you can figure out a way to spin up a browser within your .net framework and somehow capture the rendered canvas, it might be your best option.

Comment: You could try to convert the model to some format that works with a different renderer, or export from three.js to an agnostic format like .obj or .gltf, but then you'll need to find a rendering framework for .net that will load and display it.
At least with the node.js solution, you'll have a reasonable shot at getting something that looks like what you rendered in the browser.

Comment: It's not a requirement that it use WebGL. The model I have is simply along the lines of ' I have a post at the position and rotation'. I then use threejs to build that into a 3D model. So would be looking to do something similar but in dotnet.

Comment: Fair enough. I don't know of any .net serverside rendering frameworks off the top of my head, but a google revealed this:

http://timjones.io/blog/archive/2011/02/23/dotwarp-server-side-d-renderer-for

Good luck :)

Comment: Sounds like the sort of thing that would have been useful but its from 2011 and doesn't look like its maintained, which would rule out a dotnet core version. Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: Cheers! Good luck :)