# Save hidden DIV as canvas image

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, html2canvas

I used the following code to save the visible  as image.

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector('.specific'), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
        theCanvas = canvas;
        Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
    }
});
```

Is there any way that I can able to save the hidden

Comment: can you a html please

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are some solutions out there, like for example display property toggle, or render inside hidden element.

### Solution 1

Quickly toggle visibility property

```
const el = document.querySelector('.specific');
el.style.display = "block"; // or any other property, like opacity, visibility...
html2canvas(el, {...}).then((canvas) => {
   el.style.display = "none";
};
```

### Solution 2

Wrap your div (and make it visible) inside an invisible wrapper

```
<div style="position: absolute; opacity: 0; pointer-events:none;">
    <div class="specific"></div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; height: 0;">
    <div class="specific"></div>
</div>
```

### Solution 3

Using html2canvas onclone callback function you can modify object passed to renderer (I think it's the best solution)

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector('.specific'), {
    onclone: function(doc){
        doc.style.display = 'block';
        // or doc.style.opacity = '1', doc.style.visibility = 'visible' ...
    },
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        theCanvas = canvas;
        Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
    }
});
```

Comment: When onclone callback will get executed

Comment: In the beginning of html2canvas execution, before render, it' in the docs.

Comment: I tried to print a console.log inside onclone() but it's newer executed

Comment: Maybe you are using some outdated version? I have tried this and it works: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.5.0-beta4/html2canvas.min.js

Comment: I had the older version. Latest version has onclone method. It's working after changed the latest one

Comment: This doesn't work in 2021 - doc returns the window's document, so you'd need to do `doc.getElementById('whatever').style...

Comment: add z-index: -1; to all of this solutions :)

Comment: Solution 2 work for me, thanks