# Server side rendering using threeJS

Tags: node.js, three.js

I am trying to do complete server side rendering of an object using threejs and node server.

I have been able to load the model but fails to load Textures using MTLLoader.
The standard MTL loader with options suggested on web (node module "xmlhttprequest", "blob-util") fails at multiple places like - addEventListener and URL with 'blob' parameter.

Is it possible to do this with threejs and supported libraries?

My query is specific to ThreeJs loaders and make them work in server OR loaders with logic of local or remotely loading of OBJ and MTL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I render three.js in node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162510/how-do-i-render-three-js-in-node-js)

Comment: What are benefits of THREE.js in context of server-side rendering?

Comment: purpose was to keep the same APIs for client and server to make application simple for development and support purposes