# Issue with converting map_Kd texture into a usable format for three.js port

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js, porting, texture-mapping

So, this is a somewhat uncommon issue. However, I'm attempting to create a headless Node.js renderer for OBJ and MTL files with Three.js. I've managed to rewrite the loaders to load from local files instead of URLs (this works partly). Currently, I have OBJ rendering working and can load any OBJ I want. However, loading the MTL with the corresponding map_Kd texture is an issue. I have gotten it to the point of requesting the correct path for the map_Kd and also have it load the texture. However, converting the raw image data into something Three.js can understand is a different story. This is the code for TextureLoader.js

```js
class TextureLoader extends Loader {

    constructor( manager ) {

        super( manager );

    }

    async load( url, onLoad, onProgress, onError ) {
        console.log('Called texture loader load')

        const texture = new Texture();

        const loader = new ImageLoader( this.manager );
        loader.setPath( this.path );

        await loader.load( url, function ( image ) {

            console.log('Texture loader image:', image)

            texture.image = image;
            texture.needsUpdate = true;

            if ( onLoad !== undefined ) {

                onLoad( texture );

            }

        }, onProgress, onError );

        return texture;

    }

}
```

I don't think this is the issue; I'm pretty sure it's the ImageLoader.js file, as this is responsible for loading the color map. Currently, I'm using Canvas and JSDOM to try and fake an HTMLCanvasElement; however, it doesn't seem to want to render it.

```js
class ImageLoader extends Loader {
  constructor(manager) {
    super(manager);
  }

  async load(url, onLoad, onProgress, onError) {
    console.log('ImageLoader Requested:', url);
    const scope = this;
  
    const imageData = new Promise((res) => {
      fs.readFile(url, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          // Handle error
        } else {
          scope.manager.itemStart(url);
          const imageBase64 = 'data:image/png;base64,' + data.toString('base64');
          const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><body><img id="myimg" /></body>`);
          const img = dom.window.document.getElementById('myimg');
          img.onload = () => {
            const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(img.width, img.height);
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
            console.log('ImageLoader Loaded:', url);
            scope.manager.itemEnd(url);
            onLoad(canvas); // Pass the Canvas to the callback
          };
          img.src = imageBase64;
        }
      });
    })
  
    return await imageData;
  }
};
```

Iv confirmed that the texture has the image data im just not sure on what kind of datatype it requires

The current source is here https://github.com/NotReeceHarris/open-captcha/tree/aa37c7004526e8b0533e95c98ad3e6899352da9c

and this is the render i have managed to get working so far

[image: Nodejs Threejs render of a police car]

So far, I have attempted to create both an HTMLImageElement type and an HTMLCanvasElementType. However, as this is Node.js, it doesn't seem to want to recognize it. I have also attempted to modify the source.js to accept base64 images; however, it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: There is a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162510/how-do-i-render-three-js-in-node-js) however they dont go over rendering Obj with Mtl

Comment: I have a temporary workaround, im just using models that have colored materials instead of using a map_kd, this doesnt solve the issue but for now is fine